# Get Dragon Dictate to move cursor to The end of the current line?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

How do I get Dragon Dictate to move to the end of the line after correcting something on the Mac?

Answer (score -1):

Move forwards [n] words or "go back"

Comment: You can also say "press the key combo command right arrow"